# Async not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

Hi I am having problems sending emails asychronously. I have set up everything as indicated in [this tutorial.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

I have annotated my email service with `@Service`, set it up as a bean, annotated the method with `@Async`.

I have then `@Autowired` that service into a controller and used the method. Although it does not carry it out asynchronously and takes two seconds to get past `emailSerivce.sendMail();`

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

My Email Service is setup like this.

```
 @Service
    public class EmailService {

    //get log4j handler
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EmailService.class);

    // Sends an email with the following parameters
    @Async
    public Future<Page> sendEmail(CustomPropertiesForm cpf, String [] recipients, MimeBodyPart attachment, String subject, String content){

        // Initialise local variables
        Boolean success = false;
        Boolean isAuthenticationRequired = false;
        String smtpAuthUsername = null;
        String smtpAuthPassword = null;

        try{
             Thread.sleep(5000);
            logger.info("Sending Email");

            // Build properties
            Properties props = new Properties();

            if(cpf.getSmtpAuthenticationRequired().equals("YES")){
                isAuthenticationRequired = true;
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                smtpAuthUsername = cpf.getSmtpAuthUsername();
                smtpAuthPassword = cpf.getSmtpAuthPassword();
            } else {
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
            }

            if (cpf.getSmtpSSLRequired().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
                //- See more at: http://www.jvmhost.com/articles/how-to-send-mail-with-javamail-and-tomcat#sthash.3IN3wreU.dpuf
                props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");     
                props.put("mail.transport.protocol", cpf.getSmtpProtocol());
                props.put("mail.smtps.port", cpf.getSmtpHostPort());
                props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.trust", cpf.getSmtpHostName()); 
            } else {
                props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");                
            }


            props.put("mail.smtp.host", cpf.getSmtpHostName());
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", cpf.getSmtpHostPort());
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", cpf.getSmtpProtocol());

            // Create mail Session
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            mailSession.setDebug(false);    
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

            // Create Message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            // Add recipients
            for(String string : recipients){
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(string));
            }

            // Set From Address
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(cpf.getDefaultApplicationEmailAddress()));

            // Set subject
            message.setSubject(subject);            
            // Set content
            MimeBodyPart mbpText = new MimeBodyPart();
            mbpText.setText(content);

            MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            mp.addBodyPart(mbpText);        

            message.setContent(mp);            

            // Add attachment
            if(attachment != null){    
                mp.addBodyPart(attachment);
            }

            // Connect to mail server and send email
            if(isAuthenticationRequired){
                transport.connect(cpf.getSmtpHostName(), Integer.parseInt(cpf.getSmtpHostPort()), smtpAuthUsername, smtpAuthPassword);
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                transport.close();                   
            } else {
                transport.connect();
                transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                transport.close();  
            }

            success = true;
            logger.info("Email Sent");

        } catch (Exception e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage() + " " + e.getCause() + " " + e.fillInStackTrace());    
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " " + e.getCause() + " " + e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
    }    
    Page result = new Page();
    result.setName("name");
    result.setWebsite("website.com");
    return new AsyncResult<Page>(result);   
}
```

In my dispatcher servlet I set it up as a bean,

```
<bean id="emailService"
      class="ie.premiumpower.services.EmailService">
</bean>
```

I then make use of this email service from my controller,

```
@Controller
public class NotSecureController extends AbstractController {

@Autowired
private EmailService emailService;

@RequestMapping("notsecure/taskSummary/shareTaskSummary.json")
public String getQuestions(
        @RequestParam("taskInstanceId") int taskInstanceId,
        @RequestParam("emailAdresses[]") String emailAddresses[]) {


try {
        long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Email being sent at time: " + currTime);

        Future<Page> sendEmail = emailService.sendEmail(cpf, emailAddresses, null, subject, content);
        while (!(sendEmail.isDone())) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        long aftTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        aftTime = aftTime - currTime;
        System.out.println("Email finished being sent in time: " + aftTime);
        System.out.println(": " + sendEmail.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Even when I change it to return a Future it still takes 7 seconds (with the sleep).

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml  
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>           
<resource-ref>
    <description>ArcFlashMap DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/AFM_DB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>    
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoadResourcesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ie.premiumpower.services.reports.common.LoadResourcesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>            
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        -1
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />    
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="7"/>
```

And my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



<context:component-scan base-package="ie.premiumpower.controllers" />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>    
<bean id="emailService"
      class="ie.premiumpower.services.EmailService">
</bean>
```

Exception when trying to run program with component-scan pointent to ie.premiumpower.

```
        Sep 23, 2015 11:20:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet /SafeSiteLive threw load() exception
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Annotation-specified bean name 'emailService' for bean class [ie.premiumpower.services.scheduledTaskServices.EmailService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [ie.premiumpower.services.EmailService]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:274)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:215)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1862)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How did you came up with the 2 seconds delay?

Comment: See the system outs in my controller.

Comment: Which `TaskExecutor` did you specify? Did you add `@EnableAsync` to your configuration?

Comment: Because of while loop (`while (!(sendEmail.isDone()))`) it is taking 2 second.

Comment: No it takes the same amount of time with or without the while loop.

Comment: Is your service class inside `ie.premiumpower.controllers` package?

Comment: no it's inside ie.premiumpower.services.

Comment: Ok remove the emailService bean declaration from your xml and change your component scan to `ie.premiumpower` package.

Comment: Ok did this but get an exception when trying to run my program I'll post it in the main question.

Comment: Do you have 2 different EmailService class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90423/discussion-between-naman-gala-and-onetwo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Ok, can you try one thing, put the async thread to sleep for 5 seconds by calling Thread.sleep(5000). This way, you will know, that this is not only for creating async task 2 seconds are required. If that doesn't help, then remove the Thread.sleep, and do the following below.

If you would like to get the result back, use a Future tag, as mentioned below :

```
    @Async
    public Future<Page> sendEmail(params) throws InterruptedException{
   return new AsyncResult<Page>(your_result);
}
```

In your controller :

```
    Future<Page> sendEmail = sendEmail(params);
```

And check this way, if they are done :

```
 while (!(sendEmail.isDone() ) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
```

Lemme know.

Comment: Ok so it takes 7 seconds with the five second sleep.

I then changed to return a page and added the while loop but it still takes 7 seconds (updated the question).

Comment: Oh sorry that's what I meant by this question.

Comment: Ok, then post your configuration and your web.xml in main post.

Comment: Ok, for starters, change the topic of the post to 'Async not working'. Secondly, in your web.xml, you have to declare for all your filters <async-supported>true</async-supported>. Lastly, you have declared a task-pool. In your async-method, refer to the task-executor.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I invoke the async method within the same service, it doesn't have a chance to add proxy class within the same class by spring.

Required config for Spring Async

1. @EnableAsync with @Configuration
2. @Async on a public method
3. Should not call within same class

Answer (score 0):

Looking at snippet it seems like, asynchronous setting is missing. I guess adding @EnableAsync annotation, might resolves the issue.

```
@EnableAsync
@Service
public class EmailService
```

Comment: No, EnableAsync is required only when you have the @Configuration annotation.

Comment: No throws on exception when trying to run.

Comment: What exception r u getting? i guess it helps to resolve your issue

Comment: Dont use that annotation on your service layer class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem because you did not specify the return type to use the `Future` type.

Looking at the URL you give, there is a sentence that says

> The method’s return type is Future instead of Page, a requirement for any asynchronous service. This code uses the concrete implementation of AsyncResult to wrap the results of the Facebook query.

So, try to change your return method and try again.

Comment: But the sendEmail method is a void, surely that doesn't need to be FUture?

Comment: Well, if you think that it does not need to return a value. Then you can use the `java.lang.Void` class as the type. I mean, like this `Future<java.lang.Void>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it.

I changed my applicationContext to this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="ie.premiumpower.services" />      
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
        <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="10"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>          
<bean id="emailService"
   class="ie.premiumpower.services.EmailService">
</bean>
```

Placing the bean here and doing a scan on the services packaged,

I left my service annotated with @Service and the Method with @Async.

I made the @Autowired EmailService public (Don't know if this matters).

And finally I acquired the Asm library (Required by clib).

(I removed the EmailService bean from dispatcher-servlet).